# How do I identify what cassette type I have?

Tags: cassette

My chain was jumping and I looked at my cassette, let's just say it needs a lot of dental work.
So I need a new cassette and a new chain but can't find specs for the cassette type for my bike.

So what should I look at to identify what type it is in order to buy a compatible one?

I have a Schwinn Graft Pro [image]

Comment: I googled "Schwinn Graft Pro specs"  which returned http://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/schwinn-graft-pro-27-full-suspension-mountain-bike-26-in-0711034p.html and that says "27 speed".  That means 3 on the front multiplied by 9 on the back.  You have a 9 speed cassette and sram shifters.  Tooth count is proving elusive, but the Sram X5 rear mech supports a maximum of 36 tooth so its no more than that, and likely to be less.

Comment: Do you know how to replace the cassette yourself? If not, just take it into a bike shop and they'll get an appropriate part for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How to chose a new cassette:

1. the make of the drive-train, which you may find on the body of the rear derailleur. (let's assume Shimano)
2. the number of cogs on the cassette (let's assume 10)
3. the number of teeth on both the largest and the smallest cogs on the cassette (let's assume 42 and 11)

The number of cogs determines the type of chain (10 cogs = 10-speed chain) and of course the type of cassette you'll want to order. (in our case a ten-speed)
The two teeth counts tell you which cassette you'll need. In our case it would be an 11-42 cassette.

Don't forget to check the front chainrings for wear. Excessive wear makes them look like shark-teeth.

Also you'll need tools to remove the cassette, a chain-whip and a brand specific lockring tool, as well as a chaintool.

Don't throw away the worn chain too quickly, you'll need it to determine the number of links on your new chain since chains sold longer than required and have to be shortened to the correct number of links.

On YouTube you'll find a number of videos explaining the procedure.

Comment: https://www.sram.com/sram/road/products/pg-950-cassette

Comment: So there's nothing universal when it comes to cassettes? I can only buy SRAM brand cassettes or else it will give me problems? I find this odd. 9 speed Sram it is then. https://www.sram.com/sram/road/products/pg-950-cassette

Comment: @Eric Huelin: (Road)-hubs designed for SRAM take Shimano cassettes as well and the other way round. There are some compatibility issues with issues with some MTB 11-speed types, as far as I know but I lack full information on that subject. But all 9-speed may be interchanged.

Answer (score 2):

It's a standard shimano/sram compatible cassette. It is the most common 9 speed cassette available. ([assuming its 9 speed from specs listed here](http://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/schwinn-graft-pro-27-full-suspension-mountain-bike-26-in-0711034p.html)) The only real alternatives are "campagnolo" or "campy" cassettes, which are uncommon and expensive, or "freewheels" which are threaded cartridge type things, and not cassettes, and rarely come with so many speeds.

The chain can be shimano, sram, kmc, etc, as long as it is the same number of speeds as the cassette.

Technically the cassette compatibility is determined by what is called the [freehub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freehub) body, but the shimano/sram standard is virtually universal, with most brands at least.